# HTTP request in Fibaro Home Center with virtual device

Tags: request, device

I use the Fibaro Home Center Lite box and have connected several devices to it.

I would like to create a virtual device to send my data to a web server with HTTP request but I don't know how to build the request.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VD buttons your code should be like this:

```
local http = Net.FHttp("192.168.0.32", 80);
local response = http:GET("/core/api/api.php?param=2335");
```

In Main Loop section (and in scenes) it will have kinda different syntax:

```
local http = net.HTTPClient();
http : request('https://api.lifx.com/v1/lights/label:Light1/state.json?selector=label:Light1&power=on&brightness=0.7',  {
    options = {
        method = "PUT",
        headers = {
            ['Authorization'] = 'Bearer cce26ealkadj764'
        },
        data = ""
    },
    success = function(response) fibaro:debug (response.data) end,
    error = function(err) fibaro:debug ("Error:" .. err) end
});
```

Comment: In VD main loop the syntax "Net.FHttp..." works as well.